# Create Shimmer in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, highlights

So I've created many sparkles in Illustrator, but now I'm trying to make a shine or highlight.

I'm trying to replicate the highlighted circles in the second half of this animation:

[image]

It appears to just be a series of circles in varying opacities:

[image]

When I try to make it, it doesn't look blended.

Any thoughts on what would achieve this look? I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you talking about the shine/glow that moves around the flags?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to replicate this in Adobe Animate, but I need to make a flare somehow. Usually I animate with PS, but it doesn't provide me with the options I need.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to be a radius gradient from 100% white to 0% and transparent in line from 100% to 0%.

If you open the gradient editor in photoshop, on the gradient bar, you have two carrots on the top of the bar and two on the bottom.  The top two control your transparency, and the bottom two control your color.  Set both left to 100%, and both right to 0% with the color being white.

you should be able to do that to make your PNG.  I can try to post screen shots if you need them.

While the flare tool is a good idea, it uses a bunch of layered transparency effects in Illustrator that rely on overlaying an image.  when you try to export just the flare, it doesn't work right.

Comment: That def. helped! I layered a few circles behind it, with varying transparencies. Thank you to everyone for helping!

Comment: @AnnaPlatanoSmith very welcome! If the white isn't strong enough, you can always play with the slider positions, just keep the the top and bottom ones together. You can also click between the sliders to added another one the will let you adjust the step points even more. A trick that might work for what you are doing might be to use 2-100% sliders and 1-0%. That way you set a portion of the middle to be a 100% white circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Illustrator's native "Flare tool" to achieve what you are looking for.

[image: Flare tool]

Comment: So I'm needing to export this as a PNG and import it into Adobe Animate. But all I'm getting in Illustrator is a black gradient circle. I need it to be a purely white flare.